# Node fetch receive a ReadableStream and receive an incomplete response

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming

I am making a request Node fetch receive a `ReadableStream` and receive an incomplete response. The problem seen as the `ReadableStream` is not getting complete in the await.

Request:

```
static async postData(url = "") {
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "same-origin", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: "default", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
      //body: JSON.stringify(dados), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    const stream = await response.body?.getReader().read();

    let jsonBuffer = Buffer.from(stream?.value!);

    let jsonString = jsonBuffer.toString("utf8");
    console.log(jsonString);
    return JSON.parse(jsonString); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
  }
```

Response:

```
{"retorno":{"status_processamento":"3","status":"OK","pagina":1,"numero_paginas":1,"contatos":[{"contato":{"id":"715461091","codigo":"","nome":"Fabio Moreno","fantasia":"","tipo_pessoa":"F","cpf_cnpj":"","endereco":"","numero":"","complemento":"","bairro":"Vila Medon","cep":"","cidade":"Americana","uf":"SP","email":"linkiez@gmail.com","fone":"","id_lista_preco":0,"id_vendedor":"0","nome_vendedor":"","s`
```

Error:

> [1] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> [1]     at JSON.parse ()
> [1]     at TinyERP.postData (file:///home/linkiez/Desktop/Projetos/JCMserver3/dist/services/tinyERP.js:22:21)
> [1]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> [1]     at async aprovarOrcamento (file:///home/linkiez/Desktop/Projetos/JCMserver3/dist/controllers/orcamentoController.js:259:40)
> [1] nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node -q dist/index.js exited with code SIGINT
> [0] tsc --watch exited with code SIGINT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What `fetch` are you using? Both Node's [`fetch`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch) and [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) have the [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) convenience method, which does what you want with a fair bit less code.

Comment: Separately: `stream?.value!` doesn't make much sense. :-) The optional chaining means `stream` may be `null` or `undefined` and will result in `undefine`, but then you're using the non-nullish assertion operator to say it *isn't* `undefined`. At a minimum, you'd want to remove the `?`.

Comment: Im using Node's fetch, im getting the response but it is cut in half. The problem seen as the ReadableStream is not getting complete in the await

Comment: @LiNkIeZ - Again, given what you're trying to do, why not just use `json()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you're using Node.js's [`fetch`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#fetch), which is meant to be compatible with the web platform's [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

Your code isn't reading the entire response. Here's the documentation for the [`read()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read) method on the default reader returned by [`getReader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) with no arguments:

> The `read()` method of the `ReadableStreamDefaultReader` interface returns a `Promise` providing access to ***the next chunk*** in the stream's internal queue.

*(my emphasis)* That's not the entire response, that's just the first chunk of the response.

But there's no need for that code to be anywhere near that complicated, just use the built-in `json` method to read the entire response and parse it from JSON; see the `***` comments below:

```
static async postData(url = "") {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "same-origin",
        cache: "default",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        redirect: "follow",
        referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
        // *** It seems odd that there's no `body` here, given it's a POST
        // saying that it's *sending* JSON (the `Content-Type` header above
        // says what you're *sending*, not what you're expecting back).
    });
    // *** This was missing, but it's important; `fetch` only rejects on
    // *network* errors, not HTTP errors:
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    // *** Fully read the response body and parse it from JSON:
    return await response.json();
}
```

[Here's a post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic old blog about the need for the `ok` check I added above.